# Simulacrum in Scalafiddle: exception during macro expansion

Tags: scala, scala.js, simulacrum

I wanted to use [Simulacrum](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) in Scalafiddle, like:

```
import simulacrum._

@typeclass trait Ordering[T] {
    def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
    @op("<") def lt(x: T, y: T): Boolean = compare(x, y) < 0
    @op(">") def gt(x: T, y: T): Boolean = compare(x, y) > 0
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:3: error: exception during macro expansion: 
scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: not found: type op
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$3(Typers.scala:32)
    ...
```

Here is the fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/vT0X9FR/4

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, the problem is with ScalaFiddle.

If I attempt to run your code in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/) (similar web IDE for Scala), and print out the type trees generated by it, you can see the following:

```
|-- class Playground BYVALmode-EXPRmode (site: package <empty>) 
|    |-- new op("<") EXPRmode (silent: class Playground)
```

You can see that scastie is causing the generated code to be wrapped inside a `Playground` class, which is not defined in your code, but provided for you by the web IDE.

If I compile the same example in IDEA, I see the following:

```
|-- new op("<") EXPRmode (silent: package github) 
|    |-- new op BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: package github)
```

As you can see, there is no wrapping of the `op` type created by simulacrum. Because of this wrapping, simulacrum is not able to find the `op` type it generated, because it's full namespace at compile time is `Playground.op`.

To avoid this and as a workaround, wrap your traits inside an object:

```
import simulacrum._

object Foo {
  @typeclass trait Ordering[T] {
    def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
    @op("<") def lt(x: T, y: T): Boolean = compare(x, y) < 0
    @op(">") def gt(x: T, y: T): Boolean = compare(x, y) > 0
  }

  @typeclass trait Numeric[T] extends Ordering[T] {
    @op("+") def plus(x: T, y: T): T
    @op("*") def times(x: T, y: T): T
    @op("unary_-") def negate(x: T): T
    def zero: T
    def abs(x: T): T = if (lt(x, zero)) negate(x) else x
  }

  import Foo.Numeric.ops._
  def signOfTheTimes[T: Numeric](t: T): T = -(t.abs) * t
}
```